# Bad CPU type in executable LLDB MacOSX Catalina

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, lldb, i386

I am trying to debug my helloworld.s in MAC Catalina 10.15.4. My uname -p show i386 and uname -m show x86_64. 
This is my step.

```
as hello.o -o hello.o-arch i386
ld hello.o -e _main -lc -macosx_version_min 10.15.4 -o hello -arch i386  -no_pie
```

Then I got this waring "ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)"

```
sudo lldb hello
(lldb) target create "hello"
Current executable set to '/Users/hosituan/hello' (i386).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = hello`main, address = 0x00001f81
(lldb) run
error: Bad CPU type in executable
(lldb) run
error: Bad CPU type in executable
(lldb) run
```

This is my hello.s:

```
globl  _main           # set start point of program

message:
    .asciz "Hello World\n"

_main:                      # program starts here
    push    %ebp            # save base-pointer register
    sub     $8, %esp        # reserve bytes from stack to call _printf

    lea     message, %eax   # get memory address of message string...
    mov     %eax, (%esp)    # ...and store it into reserved stack area

    call    _printf         # display a "Hello World" on console

    add     $8, %esp        # free up reserved stack memory
    pop     %ebp            # restore base-pointer register
    xor     %eax, %eax      # set return code to zero
    ret                     # exit program
```

I tried to download and install two files for Mac from this link, but no help. Thanks so much.

https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-cli/issues/453

Comment: As the error message tries to tell you, 32 bit code is no longer supported on macOS.  Unfortunately, there isn't really a workaround.  I recommend you to go with 64 bit code if possible.